# div above navbar-fixed-top in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to put a div above navbar-fixed-top in bootstrap, but for some reason the div with its content does not show. I dont know what else to write here, it is asking for detail all is in a code

here is the code

```
 <div class="nav-top">
 <div class="container">
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-xs-12">fdjfdl;ffd;fjd;  fjd;ffffffffffffffffffff

 </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">

    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed"   data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
              <div class="navbar-brand" ><img src="images/logoa.png" alt="need to name it"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Главная <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">bla</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">bla</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">bla</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">blabla</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">blablabla</a></li>
                <li class="j">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Обо мне <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">blu</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

remove your **navbar-fixed-top** class from code then you get some space to show your text.Have fun
`Here is JSFiddle:`https://jsfiddle.net/arifkarim/uu0n4cyk/3/

Comment: unfortunatly that is not what i need< i need it to be fixed top and i know it can be done

Comment: I don't get it what you said but could you please tell me what you are looking for!!

Comment: i need for nav to be class fixed top and i need to have a div with phone numbers and social icons above the navigation menu, which i repeat need to be fixed to the top

Comment: yap..understand but you should write some extra code to achieve your solution. here is another tricks but as i told you, you have to customize.

Comment: this is much better but missing many components, can you redo it with my exact structure, or explain how and what you doing

Comment: I think you have not enough knowledge on Bootstrap so please take some time to study on then you will get your answer automatically.TTYL

Answer (score 0):

I know this is 4 years late but for anyone else stumbling upon this.
The fixed-top has a z-index of 1030, so just set your own element that you wish to be on top to z-index: 1050 (higher than 1030 at least).